# Route by query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

What do I do if I want a url like below (which is not defined by me, so I can't change it):

http://localhost/Something?cmd=Open&a=1&b=2

Maps to MyController.Open() action?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Open(int a, int b)
    {
        //.....
    }

    public ActionResult Close(string c)
    {
        //.....
    }
}
```

Note: there are more than one possible cmd values, each mapped to an action of the same controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom route:

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    public MyRoute()
        : base(
            "something",
            // TODO: replace the name of the controller with the actual
            // controller containing the Open and Close actions
            // What you have shown in your question is not an MVC controller.
            // In ASP.NET MVC controllers must derive from the Controller class
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "home" }), 
            new MvcRouteHandler()
        )
    { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var cmd = httpContext.Request.QueryString["cmd"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd))
        {
            rd.Values["action"] = cmd;
            return rd;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then register this custom route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // register the custom route before the default route, 
    // to ensure that it handles requests to /something
    routes.Add("something", new MyRoute());

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it when get home. Seems to be the right solution.